# My theme's default face is ignored

Tags: faces, themes

I recently changed my Linux distribution (from an old Opensuse 13.1 to Linux Mint 19, which comes with "GNU Emacs 25.2.2 of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian"), and now my very basic theme is not working correctly anymore. My theme file is only this:

```
(deftheme Labo
  "Created 2017-02-16.")

(custom-theme-set-variables  'Labo
 '(default-frame-alist (quote ((tool-bar-lines . 0) (height . 57)
                               (menu-bar-lines . 1) (width . 82)
                               (vertical-scroll-bars . right)))))

(custom-theme-set-faces  'Labo
 '(default ((t (:height 113 :foundry "1ASC"
                :family "Droid Sans Mono Slashed")))))

(provide-theme 'Labo)
```

My theme is correctly loaded from `.emacs`: `M-x customize-themes` shows it checked. `M-x describe-variable default-frame-alist` gives the correct value (as defined in the theme). But `M-x describe-face default` gives:

```
Family: DejaVu Sans Mono
Foundry: PfEd
Height: 98
```

However, changing the default face by hand in Customize works, so I guess the "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" font is not the culprit.

I'm far from being an Emacs expert. Maybe a loading order issue? The requested font is a TrueType one, placed in `~/.fonts`.

There is no error in `Messages`. How to debug this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had asked the same question on Usenet group fr.comp.applications.emacs on September, 10. I received an answer by "Joseph Girod" on December, 18 which I translate here

> The documentation of `custom-theme-set-face` states you have to either add a non-nil argument after the font specification to tell "now", that is, apply the font immediately, or call function `(custom-theme-recalc-face FACE)`.

Accordingly, I changed the relevant part of my theme into (the foundry specification was useless)

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'Labo
 '(default ((t (:height 113 :family "Droid Sans Mono Slashed")))
           t ))
```

and it works as expected.